# Testing automation - identify a button using contains

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, test-strategy

I need to make a test to `login on 5 different sites`. The issue is that some of them have a `login button`, and the others display directly the `login form`, to fill the `username` and `password`.

The only thing in common between those sites, that has a `login button` is that their class contains a `login` text in the name. I'm using the `POM model` for the pages and identify the `elements` in the following way:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "txtPassword")
private WebElement passwordField;
```

Is there a way to find those `login buttons` using `contains`?
What would be the best practice to handle this kind of operation?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to go by something else than `id`, check [this link](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/FindBy.html).

In your case, you can use `className` or `xpath` or `css` - depending on your exact HTML code.
So for example, you could have something like:

```
@FindBy(how = How.className, using = "login")
private WebElement passwordField;
```

This way, you can define the login buttons in a broader sense so all of them match a single definition.
Of course, like Peter's reply suggests, if these are different pages and you want to apply the POM strictly, you could have a different class for each page. Might seem more work to maintain at first, but what if one of your five pages changes the HTML class?

Comment: You don't need always use 'how=....' You can simply use @FindBy(css="login") , this is exactly the same as @FDM wrote, but short version.

Answer (score 1):

best practice will be to use page object design pattern. Then, each page has login method, which does login in a page-specific way.

Answer (score 0):

You always can use xpath, for example simple xpath for button with text "Login" will be (with findby of course):

```
@FindBy(xpath=".//button[text()='Login']")
private WebElement loginButton;
```

Or if You want to locate button that contains few words and You want to use only for example two of it, this will be:

```
@FindBy(xpath=".//button[contains(text(), 'Login to')]")
private WebElement FirstLoginButton;
```